How to update oracle table base on result of select?
I have two tables with following schema
tableA
    id (unique)
    count

tableB
    id (not unique)
    count

I want to sum tableB with same id and find the resulting sum not equal to same id's count in tableA and update tableA with the result of sum
For example
tableA

    row1
        id1
        count=10 
    row2
        id2
        count=5 
    row3
        id3
        count=1 


tableB
    row1
        id1
        count=5
    row2
        id1
        count=5 
    row3
        id2
        count=1 
    row4
        id2
        count=3

In the example above, only id2 have different count than the sum of tableB, so I want to update id2 in tableA to be count 4
Here is a script I used to find the id and count that have difference
 select g.id, c.count_sum, g.count
   FROM
    tableA g,
    (SELECT
       id,
       SUM(count) count_sum
     FROM tableB
     GROUP BY id) c
   where g.id = c.id and 
         c.count_sum <> g.count
         and g.extra_condition = 'dummy'

How do I insert the result of tableB sum into tableA count?

Your script to find the difference is not correct as it never uses tableB.

typo, let me correct it

Use a MERGE statement:
MERGE INTO tableA a
USING (
  SELECT id,
         SUM(count) AS total
  FROM   tableb
  GROUP BY id
) b
ON (a.id = b.id AND a.filter_condition = 'condition')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET a.count = b.total
  WHERE a.count <> b.total;

or using UPDATE with correlated sub-queries:
UPDATE tableA a
SET   count = (SELECT SUM(count) FROM tableB b WHERE b.id = a.id)
WHERE filter_condition = 'condition'
AND   count != (SELECT SUM(count) FROM tableB b WHERE b.id = a.id)

(But even though the UPDATE is less to type, it will be less efficient as there are two SELECTs from tableB whereas the MERGE only requires one.)
Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE tableA (id PRIMARY KEY, count) AS
  SELECT 1, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,  1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE tableB (id, count) AS
  SELECT 1,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,  3 FROM DUAL;

Then, after the MERGE, tableA contains:



ID
COUNT




1
10


2
4


3
1



fiddle

I was wondering if there is any difference between merge and using update + with
 select g.id, g.count, c.count_sum
  FROM
    tableA g,
    (SELECT
       id,
       SUM(count) count_sum
     FROM tableB
     GROUP BY id) c
     where g.id = c.id and 
     c.count_sum <> g.count
     and g.filter_condition = 'condition'
)
update tableA
SET tableA.count = DataToPatch.count_sum
FROM tableA
JOIN DataToPatch ON DataToPatch.id = tableA.id



@olaf WITH + UPDATE is not valid Oracle syntax - so, yes, there is a difference; MERGE is valid syntax and your query is not. fiddle

Only with 23c and above you have "UPDATE ... SET ... FROM ... WHERE ..." syntax that is the closest to "WITH + UPDATE" you can get.

update tableA set a.count=s.count_sum from
tableA a inner join (your grouping select here) s on a.id=s.id.


Are you sure this is valid Oracle syntax?
